# Compare 2 tab delimited files and output differences with column header

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, columns

I would like to compare 2 similar files on a common column.  The files will have identical headers.

`file1.txt`

```
mem_id      Date    Time    Building    
aa          bb      cc      dd
ee          ff      gg      hh
ii          jj      kk      ll
```

`file2.txt`

```
mem_id      Date    Time    Building    
aa          bb      cc      dd
ee          ff      2g      hh
ii          jj      kk      2l
```

`Command`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){A[i,NR]=$i}next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(A[i,FNR]!=$i)\ 
{print "ID#-"$1": Column",i"- File1.txt value=",A[i,FNR]" / File2.txt value= "$i}}}'\ 
file1.txt file2.txt
```

`Current Output`

```
ID#-ee: Column 3- File1.txt value= gg / File2.txt value= 2g
ID#-ii: Column 4- File1.txt value= ll / File2.txt value= 2l
```

`Desired Output`

```
mem_id#-ee: Time- file1.txt value= gg / file2.txt value= 2g
mem_id#-ii: Building- file1.txt value= ll / file2.txt value= 2l
```

I am very close.  But I would like help with a few improvements.

1- I would like to replace the “Column 3” and “Column 4” with the actual column header (Time, Building, whatever)

2- I would like to dynamically gather the file names in the output and not have to add it as part of the command (to make it universal)

3- I would like this scriptable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1- Read the contents of the first row to an array, then use that array later on.

Comment: `cat file1.txt |awk {'print $1"\t"$2"\t"$4"\t"$3'} > newfile.txt ### replaced`

Comment: but i don't understand #2 and #3 please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==1 { 
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    header[i] = $i
}
NR==FNR {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    A[i,NR] = $i
  }
  next
}
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    if (A[i,FNR] != $i)
      print "ID#-" $1 ": " header[i] "- " ARGV[1] " value= ", A[i,FNR]" / " ARGV[2] " value= "$i
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

#### Output:

```
ID#-ee: Time- file1.txt value=  gg / file2.txt value= 2g
ID#-ii: Building- file1.txt value=  ll / file2.txt value= 2l
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.  One quick question... can you suggest a way to dynamically grab the header of column 1 (as to read "mem_id")?

Comment: @cmart2112 You're welcome. The `header` array has those values. If you print `header[1]` you can refer back to column1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that I think does the job:

```
#! /bin/bash

FILE1=$1
FILE2=$2

[[ -z $FILE1 || -z $FILE2 ]] && echo "USAGE: $0 FILE1 FILE2" && exit 1

join -j 1 $FILE1 $FILE2 | 
awk '
NR == 1 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { header[i] = $i; }; NCOLS = (NF - 1)/2; } 
NR > 1 { for (i = 2; i <= NCOLS + 1; i++) { if ($i != $(i+NCOLS)) {print header[1]"#-"$1": "header[i]"- '$FILE1' value=",$i" / '$FILE2' value= "$(i+NCOLS) } } }
'
```

I applied a [`join`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/join.1.html) on the files so that I can read them in one go.

With `NR == 1`, I'm reading in the first row to an array (so that I can reuse them later.

Since I used `join`, if both files had `n` columns, the combined output has `2n-1` columns (the columns used for joining is merged). So I save the number of columns (discounting the common column) to `NCOLS`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  This script gets me very close, but it doen't not appear to eliminate the rows that are not common in column 1.

Comment: @cmart2112 are you sure? Can you give an example, because `join` discards lines without a common join column.